# Default for h:selectOneMenu with jsf

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, selectonemenu

I'm trying to set a default value for my h:selectOneMenu, but for some reason the first item (see below) is't the first item selected. The 3rd item is the "default selected" item.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bookBean.discountPercentage}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Please select a value: " noSelectionOption="true" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{bookBean.paymentMethods}" var="paymentMethod"
                   itemValue="#{paymentMethod.discountPercentage}"
                   itemLabel="#{paymentMethod}" required="true"/>
    <f:ajax listener="#{bookBean.setDiscountValue}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

So the "Please select a value" has to be the first item in the list (it is) and it has to be the selected value when opening te page, and it isn't.

Comment: What jsf version do you use? Also what scope has bookBean? Have you debugged the bookBean.discountPercentage? Does the getter returns something on page refresh?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first item isn't the selected item in **selectOneMenu** when the value returned by **value="#{bookBean.discountPercentage}"** is not null and is equal to an option from the available options.

Comment: You were right. I already evaluated this problem, but I forget the fact that my "discountPercentage" is default 0 and the 3th item has a discountPercentage of 0. Thanks